# CMD .bat file dies

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, npx

This .bat file works fine until the 3rd line.
The command on the 4th line takes a while to execute but when it's done the rest of the lines don't run

```
cd 09
cd png
FOR %%G IN (*.*) DO npx @squoosh/cli --oxipng {quality:75} "%%G"
cd ..
cd jpg
FOR %%G IN (*.*) DO npx @squoosh/cli --mozjpeg {quality:75} "%%G"
cd ..
cd ..
```

Comment: The fourth line is `cd ..`. The only reason that could possibly take a long time to run is if your hard drive is dying. Did you mean the first `for` loop with the `npx` command? If nothing is running after that, I suspect that `npx` is also a batch script and you'll need to use `call npx @squoosh/cli --oxipng {quality:75} "%%G"` instead so that the script can continue once the commands are done.

Comment: @SomethingDark you are correct.  I just downloaded the installer and `npx` is a batch file.

Comment: npx is part of the npm package.  So this Q&A should apply. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305275/creating-a-bat-file-with-npm-install-command

Comment: ty everyone.  so helpful.